# python using range function in for loop to iterate only even number

Tags: python, loops, arguments

What arguments shall you pass in a for loop range function to print all even numbers between 11 and 30(included)?

Code Syntax
for i in range(x,y,z):
Write the values of x y z in the respective order with a space between each value of x, y, and z.

Comment: Next time, check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) first.

Answer (score 0):

***for i in range(x,y,z) where x=12, y=31 & z=2***

**You can reference the docs here**

*https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/range.html*

> code example

```
for i in range(12,31,2):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

> 12
> 14
> 16
> 18
> 20
> 22
> 24
> 26
> 28
> 30

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).